# Nested list of patterns in SyntaxInformation "ArgumentsPattern"

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I have a function with the following input structure:

```
f[{{a1, n1}, {a2, n2}...}, {i1, i2,...}]
```

The first argument is a `List` of `List`s, each with exactly two elements, and the second argument is a list of symbols.

So I thought the appropriate `SyntaxInformation` to provide is

```
SyntaxInformation[f] = {  "ArgumentsPattern" -> {{{_, _} ...}, {___}}  };
```

Now let's look at some input examples (in v9.0.1)

[image: Input examples]

In the first example, it is correctly able to indicate the missing argument.  But in the second example, it is not highlighting the `c` and `h` in red (since these lists don't have exactly two arguments).

So, my guess is that `SyntaxInformation` is unable to recognize patterns that are too deep.  Is this correct?  If not, what can be done to get the right syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SyntaxInformation.html) says:

[image]

Your form is not one of these so it cannot be *expected* to work.  (It would be nice if it did of course.)

I cannot think of a way to get the syntax highlighting you seek, given this apparent limitation, but I will think about it.

Answer (score 5):

I ma not sure if this help or not but you may use `SyntaxInformation` twice but with two head functions:

```
SyntaxInformation[f] = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, {___}}};
SyntaxInformation[g] = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {{_, _} ...}};
```

[image]

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, Thanks. your (+1) is like (+10) from others:)